# Most efficient way for handling multiple files

Tags: nautilus, crash, trash, nautilus-actions

I am currently working on audio processing and I have many (approx 800) samples of 40s each. I am segmenting each file into roughly 8-12s clips based on ground truth data. This ends up creating 3200 files each time I run my code. Then I need to debug my code (if the audio isn't getting segmented satisfactorily). Nautilus hangs pretty often in this case. I have to delete permanently otherwise recycle bin crashes.

Can someone give me some useful tips and tricks to overcome/reduce this problem?

Edit : I normally do the following operations - sort by file size and play the largest file, delete all audio files if I find something wrong and see the file names in general if they are named as per requirement correctly.

Comment: I think **command line tools** will work much better than a file browser (but there are lighter file browsers than `nautilus`, for example `pcmanfm` and `thunar`). Command line tools: `ls`, `find`, `cp`, `mv`, `rm`. Please tell us which operations you need, and you can get detailed help.

Comment: Please check the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggested tools

- There are manuals in the operating system, for example

  ```
  man ls
  man find
  man sort
  man rm
  man less
  ```
- Maybe you find it better to use tutorials, that you can find via the internet, for example via the search string **linux less tutorial**.
- It is a good idea to have a **clean dedicated directory or directory tree, with only the audio file clips**, so that you need not worry about tampering with any other files, that you want to keep. It will make the commands simpler and easier to run.
- It is possible to have other files there, but then you must specify the file type for the files that you want to manage, for example `*.mp3`.
- In the following examples, I assume that you have a clean dedicated directory or directory tree, with only the audio file clips, and that all files, that you want to keep are outside that directory.
- In a terminal window you can re-use commands via the 'up-arrow' key.
- You can also create alias so that you can type very short commands and get the whole command, that will perform the action you want. More about that later if necessary.

> You normally do the following operations

- First you change directory to your dedicated directory

  ```
  cd /path-to-directory/
  ```

  for example

  ```
  cd $HOME/clips
  ```
- > sort by file size and play the largest file

  - **`ls`** if a flat structure (no subdirectories to search)

    ```
    ls -Sr
    ```
  - **`find`** and **`sort`** if there are subdirectories to search

    ```
    find -type f -printf "%s\t%p\n"|sort -n
    ```

  will sort with the largest file last.

  - If you want to play that file directly in a flat structure, you can try with

    ```
    mplayer "$(ls -S|head -n1)"
    ```

    (or use some other player).
- > delete all audio files if you find something wrong

  - **`rm`**

  In a flat directory

  ```
      rm *
  ```

  or if there are subdirectories with files to delete

  ```
      rm -r *
  ```

  If there are other file types, that you want to keep, remove only the audio files for example `mp3`,

  ```
      rm *.mp3
      rm -r *.mp3
  ```
- > and see the file names in general if they are named as per requirement
  >   correctly.

  - **`ls`** and **`less`**

    ```
    ls | less
    ```

    or if you want one file on each line

    ```
    ls -1 | less
    ```